# How to ask weather in natural way?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I wonder if I can use "how is the weather for tomorrow". Is it still common for native speaker? Because I ask for the future but I use present tense.

Comment: "Is it still common [to ask about weather] for native speakers?" It is if the native speaker is a Brit.

Comment: There are many, many ways to ask.  This would be a good question on http://ell.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask, ["What is the forecast for tomorrow?"](http://www.abc.net.au/7.30/content/2015/s4221029.htm), or even ["What is the weather for tomorrow?"](http://www.nuclit.com/about.php?t=what_is_the_weather_for_tomorrow), where it is clear that the term "weather" refers to the "weather forecast".

The present tense (*is*) is used here because the *forecast* (or prediction) is something done or available in the present, even though the event in question is in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may sound more natural to ask:

> How is the weather **going to be** tomorrow?

I feel the bolded portion corrects whatever present/future tense problem you are having. Tell me what you think because I am not certain I understand the perimeters of this question. 
Thank you!